# Working with GeoServer and OpenLayers in Android?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, android

I have an application using GeoServer and OpenLayers web platform, but must use the Android OpenLayers offline.

My doubt is the following, I can install GeoServer on Android? to work with OpenLayers using phonegap?

Do you have any suggestions on the other hand is the platform?

---

Dmitry Baryshnikov and west Efan provided links and explanations, most like to take one more question.

Today I have an application OpenLayers to be communicating with a server "GeoServer"

I would like to take my OpenLayers JavaScript in mobile, offline however, I would like somehow I store GeoServer data (WMS with JSON) that OpenLayers need on Android, or some other way to do this?

Comment: You won't be able to have a WMS serving JSON; WMS only provides map data as images.  You could try WFS if you want JSON.  You appear to be using GeoServer as some sort of generic term, however `GeoServer` is a specific software product for providing web services, such as WMS, WFS, WCS, WPS...

Answer (score 3):

GeoServer is spatial data source. Android is one of a client, such as desktop or web.
For Android you can use such SDKs:

1. NextGIS Android SDK - https://github.com/nextgis/android_maplib and https://github.com/nextgis/android_maplibui docs: http://docs.nextgis.com/ngmobile_dev/maplib/com/nextgis/maplib/api/IGISApplication.html
2. OSMDroid - https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid
3. MapBox Android SDK - https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native docs: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/
4. Glob3 https://github.com/glob3mobile/g3m
5. MapsMe https://github.com/mapsme/omim

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Dmitry Baryshnikov's great selection I can add mapsforge: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge

It also has a phonegap implementation already: https://github.com/afsuarez/mapsforge-cordova-plugin

To use it with OpenLayers you can use the tilerendering of mapsforge and load the tiles via `ol.source.XYZ` with the filepath of the mapcache.

---

To your second question, you could use a local database/storage(e.g. SQLite) to store the information from your geoserver and retrieve the information on demand to render it in OpenLayers.